# retain "+" sign in string

Tags: ajax, string, forms, base64

I am creating a base64 string. There is also '+' sign in that string. I am sending it through ajax to the database. but ajax removes the + and replace it with white pace. How I can overcome this problem

Comment: Are you using url to post base64-encoded content?
If so, you can get URL-safe version of base64 string.

Comment: Maybe your problem is in the decoding. How are you receiving the base64 string ? PHP ? Java ? node.js ? other ?

Comment: @destroy From HTML5 Canvas using `toDataURL()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you sending it to your server ?

You must [urlEncode](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm) what's in the url, or use JSON.stringify for an object you send as json.

This means you must decode it on the server side but most server technologies handle this for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not url encoding the base64 before sending it.

Run your base64 through javascript's `escape()` function before sending it.